# Should we add the backend graphql schema in the case of Apollo Client?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using backend node server with the Apollo graphql (Server side) and on the client, I'm using Apollo Client as well. 
I created a few client specific types in my client Schema for Apollo client but I'm wondering: 
Should I do the same for backend Types (models)? Just to add some sanity, etc.

Let me explain it a bit detailed with an example:

Here is the client schema: (Client specific types)

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default gql`
  type System {
    showSignInModal: Boolean!
  }

  type Robot {
    name: String!
    status: String!
  }

  type Member {
    name: String!
    isLogged: Boolean!
  }

  type Author {
    id: Int!
    posts: Int!
    name: String
  }


  input AuthorInput {
    id: Int!
    posts: Int!
    name: String
  }

`;
```

I have a query that fetches the user data from the server (Server specific data) 
so should I describe the whole User type in my schema as well?

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const GET_USER_SHORT_DATA = gql`
  mutation getUserShortData {
    me {
      id,
      email,
      name,
      profileUrl,
      locale
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using `mongoose` for your database operations. Your main types should be defined in your mongoose schema as `GraphQL` is just a query language meant for **"getting only what you want"**. So, you should add the same types in both the places. In your `mongoose` code for database handling & In your `GraphQL Schema` for query fetch support.

For Client side, if you're using a typed language like typescript, then you should define them in the client side too so as to prevent bugs & get better IDE suggestions.

Comment: Hi Yogesh. Thanks for the answer but I'm wondering about the Client side. At the server side I have the server side schema where I described User, etc. and these schema is available in GraphiQL so I can check it and see what exactly types the server has. But my main interest is: should I describe the same types in the Client schema? or is it a common practive?

Comment: Yes, it's a very common practice if you're using a typed language like typescript to prevent bugs & get better IDE suggestions.

Comment: But the Apollo schema is the dedicated thing. It doesn't have any relation to Typescript. I'm confused a bit. What if we use pure JS?

Comment: If you use vanilla js then it doesn't mean much to you because Vanilla JS is not bothered about the interfaces or types. My suggestion is to use `interfaces` only if you are using `typescript`

Comment: It looks like we have some misunderstanding here =).  Graphql (Apollo client) can be used in the case of Valila JS (Without typescript) but it has its own Types and Schema. I'm talking exactly about it. Take a look at my code example :)  and here is the graphql docs: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/
Anyway, thanks for the answers mate!

Comment: What do you mean by "its own types and schemas" here? Please tell me

Comment: sure, you can check this link https://graphql.org/learn/schema/ . It doesn't have any typescript relation. It's a graphql specific types and schema. It isn't a Typescript Type  eg.  `type MyType = { data: string }`

Comment: I understood that but let me know are you talking about `interface` like things in your code or anything else?